# Use of fork to write consumer and producer code in C language?

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, producer-consumer

I have to write a code using fork() function where one file i.e producer will open a **DATA.txt** file and add a character taken from **testfile.txt** file and pass the **turn** to consumer.c file which open the **DATA.txt** file again and take the character from the file and print it on screen. I know how the logic works but i am stuck with an infinite loop and doesn't know how to get out of it. any help will be appreciated.
**DATA and TURN cannot have more than one character at a time** 
Following are the file for the program.

```
output: 
Segmentation fault: 11
```

...

```
//main.c file

#include"header.h" //  including the header file

int main(){

FILE* fp = fopen("TURN.txt","w+"); 
if(fp== NULL){
    exit(1); // exit with an error
}
fputc('0',fp) ; // writing to file TURN.txt
fclose(fp); 
// including consumer.c and producer.c files
// now we have access to functions in consumer.c and producer.c

int pid = fork(); 
if(pid == -1) exit(1) ; // Failure exit


if(pid == 0){consumer();}
if(pid != 0){producer();}

return 0 ; // success(Erfolg)}
```

..

```
//producer.c file

#include"header.h" 

void producer(){

char t; // for TURN LOOP
char p;

FILE *fp = fopen("testfile.txt", "rt");  

while(!feof(fp)){ 
    do{
        FILE *TURN = fopen("TURN.txt", "rt");  
        t = fgetc(TURN) ; 
        fclose(TUdRN);  // closing turn file
    } while(t!= '0') ; // wait for turn 


    FILE *DATA = fopen("DATA.txt", "w+"); // opening data file to write a  character   in it
    p = fgetc(fp); // getting character from  testfile to write in data file

    fputc(p, DATA); 
    fclose(DATA) ;  // closing data file

    FILE *TURN = fopen("TURN.txt", "r+"); // opening turn file to change the value to 1 and pass the turn to consumer.c

    fputc('1', TURN);  // overwriting 1 in the turn file so now turn as only 1 in it. 
    fp++ ;  // incrementing the file pointer
} // end of the while loop

 fclose(fp);
```

}
...

```
#include"header.h" //  including the header file

void consumer (){
char c; 
char t;

while(1){

    do{
        FILE *ft = fopen("TURN.txt","r");  // opening turn file
        t = fgetc(ft) ;  
        fclose(ft) ; // closing the turn file
    } while( t!= '1' ); 

    FILE *dt = fopen("DATA.txt","r");  // opening data file to read from it
    c = fgetc(dt); 
    if(c =='\0'){ 
        break ;  
    }
    //else data file in not empty print the character on the screen in same order as testfile
    printf("%c",c) ; 

    FILE *ft = fopen("TURN.txt","r+"); 
    fputc('0',ft);  // producer.c turn

    //closing both turn and data file
    fclose(dt);  
    fclose(ft) ;
} // end of while loop
} //  end of consumer method
```

...

```
// header files for consumer. and producer.c and main.c
#ifndef HEADER_H // Including guards to avoid reimplimentation
#define HEADER_H
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
// function signatures from the producer.c and consumer.c
void producer(); 
void consumer();
#endif // !LIST_H
```

...

```
//make file
program: main.o consumer.o producer.o header.h
    gcc -o program main.c consumer.c producer.c
main.o: consumer.c producer.c header.h
    gcc -c consumer.c producer.c
consumer.o: consumer.c header.h
    gcc -c consumer.c
producer.o: producer.c header.h
    gcc -c producer.c
clean:
    rm *.o program.o
```

Comment: `fp++; // incrementing the file pointer` This is incorrect. The underlying I/O library takes care of moving the read/write pointers in the file when you do things like `fread(3)` or `fwrite(3)`. A `FILE*` is, from your point of view, an opaque structure which you know nothing about.

Comment: And if you run your code in a debugger, you should be able to determine the source of the segfault.

Comment: ok thanks for notifying about that.

Comment: but still the code runs for infinite amount of time .

Comment: Also read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code.

First of all, you should check whether your FILE pointers return NULL, because the `fopen()` function may fail and then returns NULL.

Secondly, your segmentation fault happens because you `fp++`, but you only `fopen()`'ed one file at that memory location. Incrementing pointers only works when you are working with pointers to arrays.

Thirdly, while playing around with the source, I noticed you seem to have wrong assumptions about `fgetc()`. If that function fails, it returns the `EOF` constant. However, this EOF constant is usually greater than the range of values which valid returned bytes may have, therefore the return value of `fgetc()` is of type int, to be able to indicate so.

EDIT: I replaced my previous, arguably pretty terrible reseponse. The comments beneath basically refer to my error in copy-pasting where the producer ended up waiting for `'1'`, which gave me a wrong impression about the situation.

Comment: So what do you advise  me to do in that situation because i can't figure out how to resolve that issue ?

Comment: I thought I had the problem, though it turns out producer is indeed waiting for '0', I somehow came to think it wrongly waited for '1'. However, the problem with the source after trying to build it and running it against valgrind is that there's a meaningless instruction in producer.c: `fp++`. Not only does it do nothing useful, it also causes the segfault you're expriencing.

Comment: I also produced a working version from your code you can see here: https://gist.github.com/mar77i/d78fd8728225e3eead1d3645414ecfb5

Answer (score 1):

You should make your parent process wait for its child. Try this:

```
pid = fork();
if(pid < 0){
//print some kind of error
} else if(pid == 0){
        producer();
        exit(0);
} else if(pid > 0){
        wait(&childStatus);// wait for the child to finish
        consumer();
}
```

*childStatus is a normal int variable that is being assigned in the blocking wait function.